# How to debug : Safari, FF tell me certificate revoked, but it is valid

Tags: ssl-certificate

On Mac OS X 10.13 High Sierra, I am visiting a site, https://www.saintanneshospital.org, and Safari and Firefox tell me the certificate has been revoked; however when I inspect the certificate it is clearly valid.

This happens only on my computer, and only on Safari and Firefox.

```
  $ curl --insecure -v https://www.saintanneshospital.org 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { cert=0 } /^\* SSL connection/ { cert=1 } /^\*/ { if (cert) print }'
  * SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
  * ALPN, server accepted to use h2
  * Server certificate:
  *  subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=steward.org
  *  start date: Oct 20 20:10:01 2017 GMT
  *  expire date: Sep 21 18:03:03 2020 GMT
  *  issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; OU=http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
  *  SSL certificate verify ok.
  * Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
  * Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
  * Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
  * Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x7fb0da805400)
  * Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
  * Connection #0 to host www.saintanneshospital.org left intact
```

What is the best way to debug why Safari and FF think this certificate is revoked, even though it is valid?

I have restarted my computer, tried a VPN, and confirmed that the affected sites do not have local /etc/hosts entries.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at the certificate chain in Firefox and other browsers. The certificate chain seems to be valid, but there is one (probably) untrusted certificate:

The root certificate "Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority" uses SHA-1 for hashing, browsers like Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari don't trust SHA-1 certs anymore. The certificate for https://www.saintanneshospital.org/ might be reissued with a SHA-2 root certificate.

See [Google Security Blog - SHA-1 Certificates in Chrome](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/11/sha-1-certificates-in-chrome.html), [Mozilla Security Blog - Phasing Out SHA-1 on the Public Web](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/18/phasing-out-sha-1-on-the-public-web/) and [Apple Support - Move to SHA-256 signed certificates to avoid connection failures](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207459).

The certificate is also issued for the site steward.org, not www.saintanneshospital.org.

Comment: Thanks for the SHA-1 / SHA-2 information, that makes sense!

Comment: @alberto56 I think that the certificate is not issued for the site is the main problem you have. If I browser to steward.org the same root certificate seems to be trusted.